# HTML CSS JS prettify - can't find automatic switch to double quotes

Tags: javascript, plugins, sublimetext3

I do not know if this belongs here, but I just installed HTML/CSS/JS prettify, and the program does not automatically convert single quotes to double quotes. Is there a setting, or has anyone hand-coded a rule for this ?

Answer (score 0):

[HTML-CSS-JS Prettify](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify) uses [JS Beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) under the hood to drive its prettification.  You can drive your own options for this by [using a `.jsbeautifyrc` file](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify#using-your-own-jsbeautifyrc-options).  Unfortunately, support for quote-style support has [been an open issue since 2014](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/483).  As it stands currently there is no mention of quotes [in the current set of options](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify#options).

On the upside, you have alternatives for getting the behavior you seek.  Linters like [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) have string-style support or you could look into [writing your own macro](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/macros.html).  Alternately, you could seek a different plugin that supports the features you seek.

*(Also worth noting, in open quote-style issue in Github, [this comment](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/483#issuecomment-130699105) claims to have a option to alter the library's code to alter quote behavior.  Leveraging this approach would probably involve a lot of forking and more trouble than it's worth, but depending on how determined you are, it might be worth consideration.)*